# Find the vectors such that the parametric curve $g(t)=h_0+ th_1+ t^ 2h_2+ t^3h_3$ passes through points

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm stuck with this problem: "Find the vectors $h_0...h_3 ∈ ℝ^2$ such that the parametric curve   $g(t)=h_0+ th_1+ t^ 2h_2+ t^3h_3$ passes through $(0,0)$ when $t=0$, $(2,1)$ when $t=1$, $(1,3)$ when $t=2$, $(,4)$ when $t=3$".

My thoughts: if $t=0$, then $h_0$ passes through (2,1). I think I have to build a system of equations.

Thank you for your help.